# How to force Django Admin to use select_related?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-orm

One of my models is particularily complex. When I try to edit it in Django Admin it performs 1042 queries and takes over 9 seconds to process.

I know I can replace a few of the drop-downs with `raw_id_fields`, but I think the bigger bottleneck is that it's not performing a `select_related()` as it should.

Can I get the admin site to do this?

Answer (score 54):

you can try this

```
class Foo(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_select_related = (
        'foreign_key1',
        'foreign_key2',
    )
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this addresses the original query. The `list_select_related` attribute is for the Admin _listing_ page, and not the object _edit_ page. Certainly in my experience with this same problem, having list related set does not speed up the edit page, only the list and select page.

Answer (score 45):

Although dr jimbob's answer makes sense, for my needs, I was able to simply override the get_queryset() method with a one-liner, even selecting a foreign key's foreign key.  Maybe this could be helpful to someone.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyModel
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related(
            'foreign_key1', 'foreign_key2__fk2_foreign_key')
```

Comment: queryset has been renamed to [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on the **change** page. I.e., form is still making thousands of queries to get related instances. Is it just me, or does this work for others? django==1.11.3

Comment: It gives this error: 
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Answer (score 14):

For my particular model, the particularly slow aspect is going through ForeignKeys  when they were being displayed in forms, which aren't called using `select_related`, so that's the part I'm going to speed up.

Looking through the relevant django source, you see in `django/contrib/admin/options.py`  that the method `formfield_for_foreignkeys` takes each FK `db_field` and calls the `ForeignKey` class's  `formfield` method, which is defined in django/db/models/fields/related/ like:

```
def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    db = kwargs.pop('using', None)
    defaults = {
        'form_class': forms.ModelChoiceField,
        'queryset': self.rel.to._default_manager.using(db).complex_filter(self.rel.limit_choices_to),
        'to_field_name': self.rel.field_name,
    }
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(ForeignKey, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

From this, we see if we provide the `db_field` with a `kwargs['queryset']` we can define a custom queryset that will be use select_related (this can be provided by `formfield_for_foreignkey`).

So basically what we want to do is override `admin.ModelAdmin` with `SelectRelatedModelAdmin` and then make our ModelAdmin subclasses of `SelectRelatedModelAdmin` instead of `admin.ModelAdmin`

```
class SelectRelatedModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if 'queryset' in kwargs:
            kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].select_related()
        else:
            db = kwargs.pop('using', None)
            kwargs['queryset'] = db_field.rel.to._default_manager.using(db).complex_filter(db_field.rel.limit_choices_to).select_related()
        return super(SelectRelatedModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

This code sample doesn't cover admin `Inline`s or `ManyToManyField`s, or foreign_key traversal in functions called by `readonly_fields`  or custom select_related queries, but a similar approach should work for those cases.

Comment: This could be simplified by `get_field_queryset` (although it is undocumented and therefore could be changed in the future).

Answer (score 9):

In Django 2.0+, a good way to improve performance of ForeignKey and ManyToMany relationships is to use [autocomplete fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields).

These fields don't show all related objects and therefore load with many fewer queries.

Answer (score 7):

For the admin edit/change a specific item page, foreign key select boxes may take a long time to load, to alter the way django queries the data for the foreign key:

[Django docs on Using formfield_for_foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

Say I have a field called `foo` on my `Example` model, and I wish to select ralated `bar` objects:

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
            if db_field.name == "foo":
                kwargs["queryset"] = Example.objects.select_related('bar')
            return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to add another option that was the most suitable for my use case.

As others have pointed out, the problem is often loading the data for select boxes. `list_select_related` does not help in this case.

In case you don't actually want to edit the foreign key field via admin, the easiest fix is making the respective field readonly:

```py
class Foo(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('foreign_key_field1','foreign_key_field2',)
```

You can still display these fields, there will simply not be a select box, hence Django does not need to retrieve all the select box options from the database.