# Problem with query optimization in Django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

I came across the fact that when I try to open the object creation window FriendlyMatch, it takes a lot of time. About 2 minutes. Through the django debug toolbar I found out that there were 4300 SQL queries. Here are my models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    """Модель игрока"""

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="player", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Игрок"
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        related_name="team_player",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Команда",
    )

    class Meta:
        """Мета класс модели Игрока"""

        verbose_name = "Игрок"
        verbose_name_plural = "Игроки"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Игрок {self.user.username}"

class FriendlyMatch(models.Model):
    """Модель Дружеского матча"""

    date_start = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Дата и время начала", null=True, blank=True
    )
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="Дата и время окончания", null=True, blank=True
    )
    duration_macth = models.SmallIntegerField(
        verbose_name="Длительность дружеского матча", default=3, null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name="creator_friendly_match",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Создатель",
    )
    player_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="friendly_match_player1",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Игрок 1",
    )
    player_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="friendly_match_player2",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Игрок 2",
    )
    first_game_winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="first_game_winner_friendly_match",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Победитель первой игры",
    )
    second_game_winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="second_game_winner_friendly_match",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Победитель второй игры",
    )
    third_game_winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="third_game_winner_friendly_match",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Победитель третьей игры",
    )
    fourth_game_winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="fourth_game_winner_friendly_match",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Победитель четвертой игры",
    )
    fifth_game_winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="fifth_game_winner_friendly_match",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="Победитель пятой игры",
    )
    winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name="friendly_match_winner_friendly_match",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="Победитель",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    status_friendly_match = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Статус дружеского матча",
        choices=StatusChoices.choices,
        max_length=64,
        default=StatusChoices.NOT_STARTED,
    )

    class Meta:
        """Мета класс для Дружеского матча"""

        verbose_name = "Дружеский матч"
        verbose_name_plural = "Дружеский матчи"
```

Here are my admin model for FriendlyMatch model:

```
@admin.register(FriendlyMatch)
class FriendlyMatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "id", "date_start", "player_1", "player_2", "status_friendly_match")
```

While I was looking for a solution, I found that this is affected by the `__str__` method of related models. I removed the `__str__` method from the Player model and then the number of queries decreased and everything became normal with SQL queries. How can you optimize queries without removing the `__str__` method from the Player model?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34985936/4151233

Answer (score 0):

You can use **list_select_related** to tell Django modeladmin class to use select_related() in retrieving the list of objects on the admin change list page. This can save you a bunch of database queries.

Also You can combine **only()** method to specify the set of fields, you want to retrieve in queryset.

```
@admin.register(FriendlyMatch)
class FriendlyMatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "date_start", "player_1", "player_2", "status_friendly_match")
    list_select_related = ["player_1", "player_2"]
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.only(
            "id", "date_start", "status_friendly_match", "player_1_id", "player_1__user", "player_2_id", "player_2__user"
        )
        return qs
```

If you want to display username of player and data retrieve in one query. You can use below code.

```
@admin.register(FriendlyMatch)
class FriendlyMatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("id", "date_start", "player_1", "player_2", "status_friendly_match")
    list_select_related = ["player_1", "player_2", "player_1__user", "player_2__user"]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.only(
            "id", "date_start", "status_friendly_match", "player_1_id", "player_1__user__username", "player_2_id", "player_2__user__username"
        )
        return qs
```